# Issue with Last N Months

Tags: powerbi, business-intelligence

I have data for last 2 months of a year 2018.I have created all the necessary measures and columns as well as tables following this tutorial http://sqljason.com/2018/03/display-last-n-months-selected-month-using-single-date-dimension-in-powe....This is my dashboard.
[image]

but when i am choosing the date as August 2018 and selecting the slider to show the data for last 2( or any number) months then i am not getting the required result. This is the measure i am using

Scan (last n months) = 
CALCULATE (
    COUNT('Scan'[Data ID]),
    DATESINPERIOD ('Date'[Date],MAX('Date'[Date]),-[N Value],MONTH )
)

No data for previous months for August 2018

No data for previous months of August 2018
[image]